# Spring - Values from property file not loaded while consuming Web Service

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

I consume a web service in spring and get values. To do that I use GenericHandler Class to set headers for web service XML, to fill up credentials and other links in the XML I use property file and load them. However, I am not able to load values into the variables. Here are my code,

```
@Component
Class WSAuthentication extends GenericHandler
{
    @Value("${webservice.consumerId}")
    private String consumerIdString;

    @Override
    public QName[] getHeaders()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext context)
    {
        .... // SOAP Message context codes
        System.out.println(consumerIdString);
        // the above line Prints null 
    }

}
```

Web Service Handler class as follows:

```
import javax.xml.rpc.handler.HandlerInfo;
import javax.xml.rpc.handler.HandlerRegistry;
import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;

public class WSHandler
{
    public StubClass addHandlerToGetInfo()
    {
        ....// Web Service stub codes
        HandlerRegistry handlerRegistryObject = locatorStubObject.getHandlerRegistry();
        List chain = handlerRegistryObject.getHandlerChain((QName)locatorStubObject.getPorts().next());
        HandlerInfo handlerInfoObject = new HandlerInfo();
        handlerInfoObject.setHandlerClass(WSAuthentication.class);
        chain.add(handlerInfoObject);
       return stubObject;
    }

}
```

In another class I use this web service to get the code, I invoke this code in a method annotated as @PostProcess of another bean,

```
....// Consuming  code goes here
WSHandler wsHandlerObj = new WSHandler();
StubClass stubObj = wsHandlerObj.addHandlerToGetInfo();
// Invoking WS Stub methods to get values
WSResponseClass responseObj = stubObj.getProfile(id);
```

Here I am not able to get consumerIdString object from properties, on the other hand I am able to hard code the value in the WSAuthentication class and it goes good when I try executing that way. Loading from property file gives a null object when I tried to access that member variable.

My questions:

- Will an instance of class WSAuthentication be created by
  HandlerInfo? Or How does it access the WSAuthentication class?
- Does the HandlerInfo gets the web service header
  through Class instance of WSAuthentication?
- Is there any other way
  to do this?

Or shall I use reflection to initialize the member variables of the class?
Please help me out, Thank you!

Comment: Did you add component scan of the package which contains WSAuthentication?

Comment: Yes I added the package.

Comment: One of the things which you can do to test if this is related to HandlerInfo or not is, take an @Autowired instance in your PostProcessor bean and check if you are able to get the consumerIdString.

Comment: How do you ask spring to load the properties file ?

Comment: You do that using `@PropertySource(value = "classpath:app-config.properties")`  include the path of the properties file relative to classpath

Comment: @SergeBallesta Through spring-servlet.xml I load the property file.

<util:properties id="env" location="classpath:application.properties">

Comment: @shruti1810 I tried accessing consumerIdString through an Autowired bean, even then I am not able to get the value, its throwing NullPointerException.

Comment: If the getter gave you NPE, that means the instance has not been created. Can you please make sure you have included the component-scan tag?

Comment: Yes @shruti1810 I have double checked the config's, the package is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Spring Reference Manual, appendix E on XML Schema-based configuration,

```
<util:properties id="env" location="classpath:application.properties">
```

is a shortcut for :

```
<!-- creates a java.util.Properties instance with values loaded from supplied location -->
<bean id="env" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="location" value="classpath:application.properties"/>
</bean>
```

That means that those properties should be accessed via their containing bean.

I think that what you want to achieve is using a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, which should be declared as :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/application.properties"/>
```

shortcut for :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations" value="classpath:/application.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Because here properties are directly available to configure other beans.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting WSAuthentication as Handler as follows:
**handlerInfoObject.setHandlerClass(WSAuthentication.class);**

*I think it is taking it as a plain bean instead of getting from Spring ApplicationContext, and hence no value is set for @Value annotated property.*

Just to confirm inject any other Spring bean and see its value. If it is null means the instance for WSAuthentication is being created using Reflection instead of using Spring.